# if f(x)>0 and f''(x)≤0 for x>0, show that f'(x)≥0 for x>0.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I can think it intuitively, if f' is negative, then f is decreasing, but since f'' is negative too, f will decrease faster and faster. so f will be negative. but i cannot show it precisely. Is there someone to help me about that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is a point $v$ at which
$f'(v)<0$,
fox $x\ge v$ we have
$f'(x) \le f'(v)$
so that
$f(x) \le f(v)+f'(v)(x-v)$.

Making $x$ large enough
($x \gt v-f(v)/f'(v)$)
will make this negative.